# javascript convert string that has image url into attr

Tags: jquery, image, url

I am trying to figure out how to convert a user entered string which contains an image url, to display as an image by adding the img attr.

Here is what i have been playing with:

```
$(".message_content").each(function() {
    var text = $(this).text();
    text = text.replace("http://www.example.org/myimage.jpg", "<img src="http://www.example.org/myimage.jpg"> ");
    $(this).text(text);
});
```

Although this doesnt work, anybody tried anything similar?

Comment: What is the string entered by the user?

Answer (score 3):

Escape the `"`.

```
text = text.replace("http://www.example.org/myimage.jpg",
  "<img src=\"http://www.example.org/myimage.jpg\"> ");
```

More general:

```
var userinput = "http://www.example.org/myimage.jpg";
text = text.replace(userinput, "<img src=\"" + userinput + "\">");
```

Comment: Yeah or use single quotes in your JS: `text = text.replace('http://www.example.org/myimage.jpg', '<img src="http://www.example.org/myimage.jpg">');`